# Xsl-fo How to render whole report but also single elements

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a document that consists of about 40 pages. It consists of nested report elements like sections, chapters, pictures, paragraphs, tables and charts.

Each element has an attribute "layout" and an attribute "pagemaster".

"pagemaster" should be responsible for which page-master-reference is used and "layout" for the appearance on the page. (like font styles etc)

My goal is that each element has its own render information based on these attributes, so that the complete document as well as each single element can be rendered on its own.

In addition, I need to manage the static-content individually. 
(For example, there are differences in the number of pages position for even and odd pages, or whether a section has a table of contents)

I have already tried to group my elements using the pagemaster attribute. This works fine and I can specify for each element which simple-page-master should be used.

Problems I get now for example if a section should have a table of contents. For this I would have to move a static page in front of it to ONLY render the table of contents.

Here is a rough overview of the structure of my xml code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <report>
        <layout></layout>
        <namecontent>REPORT</namecontent>
        <reportelements>
            <section>
                <layout>section</layout>
                <pagemaster></pagemaster>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <startatnewpage>true</startatnewpage>
                <titlecontent>Preface</titlecontent>
                <subtitlecontent />
                <notes />
                <reportelements>
                    <picture>
                        <layout>picture_title</layout>
                        <pagemaster>TITLEPAGE</pagemaster>
                        <visible>true</visible>
                        <startatnewpage>false</startatnewpage>
                        <titlecontent>Titlepicture</titlecontent>
                        <subtitlecontent />
                        <notes />
                        <reportelements />
                        <path>files\Titelpicture_17350276.Jpeg</path>
                        <footnote>Footnote</footnote>
                    </picture>
                    <section>
                        <layout>section_wide</layout>
                        <pagemaster>DIN-A4-VERTICAL</pagemaster>
                        <!-- Section should have a table of content -->
                        <hastoc>true</hastoc>
                        <visible>true</visible>
                        <startatnewpage>true</startatnewpage>
                        <titlecontent>This Section is not indented</titlecontent>
                        <subtitlecontent />
                        <notes />
                        <reportelements>
                            <paragraph>
                                <layout>paragraph_indented.xsl</layout>
                                <pagemaster>DIN-A4-HORIZONTAL</pagemaster>
                                <visible>true</visible>
                                <startatnewpage>false</startatnewpage>
                                <titlecontent>This Paragraph is not indented</titlecontent>
                                <subtitlecontent />
                                <notes />
                                <reportelements />
                                <showtitle>true</showtitle>
                                <language>de</language>
                                <textcontent>
                                    TEXT OF Paragarph
                                </textcontent>
                            </paragraph>
                                  .
                                  .
                                  .
                          <!-- and so on -->
```

And here is a little insight into my grouping-page-sequence which should call the layouting templates

```xml
            .
<!-- simple-page-masters defined here -->  
            .
            .  
</fo:layout-master-set>

            <xsl:for-each-group select=".//reportelements/*[pagemaster != '']" group-adjacent="pagemaster">

                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:call-template name="STATIC-CONTENT">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pageMaster" select="current-grouping-key()" />
                    </xsl:call-template>

                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>

            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="STATIC-CONTENT">
        <xsl:param name="pageMaster" />
        <xsl:if test="$pageMaster = 'TITLEPAGE'">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <fo:block text-align="right">
                    <fo:external-graphic src="url(file:C:\Logo.pdf)" content-width="6cm" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is that I have absolutely no idea how to get the flexibility as described above or if this is possible at all?

Comment: If you were using AH Formatter, then you could put the ToC in a nested `fo:page-sequence` (see https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf66/ahf-ext.html#fo.page-sequence), but that's not an option with FOP.  You might need to use something like Crane Softwright's PSMI (see https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/resources/psmi/) and post-process the output of your XSLT to split some `fo:page-sequence` and 'lift' the extra `fo:page-sequence` for ToC, etc., to the top level.

Comment: I am using FOP... i tried adding `xmlns:psmi="http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/resources/psmi"` to my stylesheet. When i use the psmi:page-sequence as described in the examples i get the error: `Unknown formatting object "{http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/resources/psmi}page-sequence" encountered`

Comment: psmi.xsl inputs XSL-FO and pull the `{http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/resources/psmi}page-sequence` to top level. Have you run psmi.xsl after you generated XSL-FO file?

Comment: I've never used PSMI myself, but you need to run the result from your XSLT through the PSMI XSLT to get something that you can feed to FOP.

Comment: I always run fop with console command: `fop.bat -xml myXmlFile.xml -xsl myXslFile.xsl -pdf outputPDF.pdf` How can i run psmi.xsl on the xsl-fo file?

Comment: Use Apache Ant instead of `fop.bat`. In Ant `build.xml`, make three target. First, invoke `xslt` task for your XML to XSL-FO stylesheet. Second, invoke `xslt` task setting the XSL file as psmi.xsl, input as your stylesheet result, output as XSL-FO file. Third invoke `org.apache.fop.cli.Main` by `java` task setting parameter `-fo` as result of `psmi.xsl`, `-pdf` as output PDF file.