# How to interrupt a page-sequence to insert another page-sequence

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Via `xsl:for-each-group` I group my data with a property `pagemaster`. For this group I assign the `page-sequence` in the attribute `pagemaster`. Then the template is called for each element in this group.

Now to my question: is it somehow possible that I leave the current `page-sequence` in the for-each loop to insert another `page-sequence` and then continue with the previous one?

As an example, let's assume that all elements in the group should be rendered on blue pages, but if an element has a certain attribute, a red page will be inserted at this place.

My code section looks like this:

```xml
                       .            
        <!-- master-set defined here -->
                       .
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <xsl:for-each-group select=".//reportelements/*[pagemaster != '']" group-adjacent="pagemaster">

                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="{current-grouping-key()}">

                    <!-- Static-Content per pagemaster Group -->
                    <xsl:call-template name="STATIC-CONTENT">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pageMaster" select="current-grouping-key()" />
                    </xsl:call-template>

                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <!-- Here, for example, i would like to check if the current element (.) 
                            is from type "section" and the attribute "hastoc" is true.
                            If yes the current page sequence should be interrupted and a new page-sequence 
                            should be inserted on which the table of contents is rendered. -->
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>

            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="STATIC-CONTENT">
        <xsl:param name="pageMaster" />
        <xsl:if test="$pageMaster = 'TITLEPAGE'">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <fo:block text-align="right">
                    <fo:external-graphic src="url(file:C\Logo.pdf)" content-width="6cm" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Xml Code looks like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <report>
        <layout>report.xsl</layout>
        <namecontent>Report</namecontent>
        <reportelements>
            <section>
                <layout>section_normal</layout>
                <pagemaster></pagemaster>
                <titlecontent>Vorspann</titlecontent>
                <hastoc>false</hastoc>
                <reportelements>
                    <picture>
                        <layout>picture_title</layout>
                        <pagemaster>TITLEPAGE</pagemaster>
                        <titlecontent>Titelpicture</titlecontent>
                        <reportelements />
                        <path>files\Titelpicture213124.Jpeg</path>
                    </picture>
                    <section>
                        <layout>section_leader.xsl</layout>
                        <pagemaster>DIN-A4-HEADER-ODD-EVEN</pagemaster>
                        <titlecontent>Profil</titlecontent>
                        <hastoc>true</hastoc>
                        <reportelements>
                            <paragraph>
                                <layout>paragraph_leader.xsl</layout>
                                <pagemaster>DIN-A4-HEADER-ODD-EVEN</pagemaster>
                                <titlecontent>p1</titlecontent>
                                <reportelements />
                                <textcontent>paragraph_leader 1 text</textcontent>
                            </paragraph>
                            <paragraph>
                                <layout>paragraph_leader.xsl</layout>
                                <pagemaster>DIN-A4-HEADER-ODD-EVEN</pagemaster>
                                <titlecontent>p2</titlecontent>
                                <reportelements />
                                <textcontent>paragraph_leader 2 text</textcontent>
                            </paragraph>
                                 .
                                 .
                                 .
                                 .
```

I am using the Apache Formatting Object Processor 2.3

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are struggling with the XSLT to create the desired XSL-FO structure or with the needed XSL-FO structure. If the group-adjacent does work as desired maybe you need to change that and or nest it with another one that checks the condition you have shown in the comment. Anyway, it might help to show the XML structure you have and the XSL-FO you want to create with XSLT.

Comment: As Martin said please show the XML structure otherwise nobody is going to understand what you mean by type "section", and maybe not even then - if you think it might be difficult to understand what is meant by type "section" please clarify.

Comment: This appears to be a variation on https://stackoverflow.com/q/57871721/4092205

Comment: @Tony Graham It actually is... I just thought i need to simplify my problem. 

I will add some XML to clarify my problem